# Modify Json to use into React beautiful Drag and drop

Tags: json, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I am using [this](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/tree/master/stories/src) library for react drag and drop functionality. However, my json is in this format

```
[
  {
    "id": "5f7",
    "itemName": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "id": "780",
    "itemName": "CRD"
  },
]
```

However, all the tutorial points, i will need something like this:

```
[
  'item1': {
    "id": "5f7",
    "itemName": "ABC"
  },
  'item2': {
    "id": "780",
    "itemName": "CRD"
  }
]
```

So how can i modify my json and add id for drag and drop functionalities. Even if there is any other way of achieving this then i really appreciate that.

Comment: `json2 = json1.map((el, i) => ({ ['item'+i]: el }))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with plain javascript, loop through your item's array with `map()` and create a new array that encapsulates the item, see following example:

```js
var currentArray = [{
  "id": "5f7",
  "itemName": "ABC"
},
{
  "id": "780",
  "itemName": "CRD"
}];

var result = "", sep = "";

currentArray.forEach((el, i) => {
  result += sep + "\"item" + (i+1) + "\"";
  result += ": " + JSON.stringify(el);
  sep = ", ";
});

console.log(JSON.parse("{" + result + "}"));
```

Comment: is there any way i can do something like this {'item1': {
    "id": "5f7",
    "itemName": "ABC"
  },
  'item2': {
    "id": "780",
    "itemName": "CRD"
  }} .So removing array and put json object inside multiple json object.

Comment: You can use `JSON.stringify`, see my updated snippet.

Comment: You have at least to wrap every elements in an array.

Comment: Well, I see... if you really want a string like that you wrote above, take a look to my snippet (the `result` variable)